# SQLite column in table has same name as table

Tags: sql, sqlite, join, select

Hi there I have a database movies that contains a table country, with a column also called country. when attempting to use this column I have tried

```
country."country"
country.country
country FROM country
```

screenshot of my screen showing that there is a table named country and a column also called country, with the error in the right hand sidebar:

[image: screenshot of my screen showing that there is a table named country and a column also called country, with the error in the right hand sidebar]

but the fact that they are the same name just keeps throwing an error. I am about to put my head through a wall I'm getting so frustrated. I have combed google and stack, but they just require that the table not have the same name as the database. I cannot seem to find a fix for this, any help is appreciated, and I am sorry if this has indeed been posted and answered elsewhere and I somehow missed it.

Comment: you have not a table named country in your code  ..  try add  the proper join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not about the table/column name: having a table column with the same name as the table it belongs to is unambiguous in SQL, since the syntax is clear enough about where a column name or a table name is expected.

Table `country` is not part of the `from` clause of your query, hence it is not available in the `select` clause.

You need to `join` that table, presumably with the `incountry` table:

```
inner join country on country.cid = incountry.cid
```

Then you can add `country.country` to the `select` clause.

Comment: This actually fixed it, thank you so much. I think the error led me to believe that the problem lied within my table/column names but you were right! thank you very much!!!